# SqlDataReader não retorna informação do banco

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados

> Esse DataReader abaixo quando digita o código do produto ele mostra o nome do produto em outro textbox, funciona ok, mas quando ao invés de buscar pelo código buscar pelo codigobarra ele não traz o nome na outra textbox. Alguém poderia ajudar por favor.
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
            string constring = @"Data Source=TI02;Initial Catalog=Loja;Integrated Security=True";  
            //string Query = "select * from produtos where codigo=' " + textBox1.Text + " ';"; //esse funciona 
            string Query = "select * from produtos where codigobarra=' " + textBox1.Text + " ';";// esse não funciona

            SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            SqlDataReader myReader;


                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string snome = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("nome")).ToString();
                    textBox2.Text = snome;
                    string sPreco = myReader.GetDecimal(myReader.GetOrdinal("preco")).ToString();
                    TextBoxValor.Text = sPreco;
                }
```

Comment: Acrescente mais informações: Está recebendo algum código de erro ou simplesmente não mostra nada? Poderia mostrar alguns registros da tabela para compreendermos melhor? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: consegui resolver assim:                                                                                        ` string campo;
  campo = textBox1.Text;                                                   
  string Query = "select * from produtos where codigobarra='" + campo + "' ";`